# Functionality of zoo_async operation

Tags: apache, apache-zookeeper

Zookeeper API contains an operation called zoo_async(). The documentation says that the given operation is used to

> Flush the leader Channel

Can someone please explain the functionality of this operation and suggest some use cases that we might need to use this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for this function is in [zookeeper.c](https://github.com/apache/zookeeper/blob/release-3.4.10/src/c/src/zookeeper.c#L2958-L2985).  We can see that it is sending a `SyncRequest` to the ZooKeeper server:

```
struct SyncRequest req;
```

This means that `zoo_async` in the C client API is equivalent to [`sync`](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.10/api/org/apache/zookeeper/ZooKeeper.html#sync(java.lang.String,%20org.apache.zookeeper.AsyncCallback.VoidCallback,%20java.lang.Object)) in the Java client API.

This method can be called to guarantee that the client's view of ZooKeeper state is fully caught up with the server-side view.  This method is used only rarely in practice.  Most ZooKeeper usage patterns don't require it.  The Apache ZooKeeper documentation on [Consistency Guarantees](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.10/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkGuarantees) contains further discussion about the problem of simultaneously consistent cross-client views and how the `sync` method can be applied to the problem.

You might be wondering about the naming inconsistency between `async` in the C API and `sync` in the Java API.  The confusion arises from the fact that the operation is synchronizing state between client and server, but it executes asynchronously, with the client receiving a callback upon completion.  Thus, it is a "asynchronous synchronization".  It appears the naming in the C API chose to emphasize the asynchronous nature of the function, while the naming in the Java API chose to emphasize the action performed.